# How should I map error responses with code 200 properly?

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I use RestKit 0.20 and iOS 7.

I want to map error response from REST API. It is how it looks like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_code": 5,
    "error_msg": "User authorization failed: invalid access_token.",
    "request_params": [
      {
        "key": "oauth",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "method",
        "value": "execute.MusicNews"
      },
      {
        "key": "access_token",
        "value": "e2276858338752ef3f6f974b0996e4a1755a5b17178781a6602be1e6c2aa0e23bfb89ec040c787d2dc753"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is that API returns errors with code `200`.

It's not a problem to create `RKObjectMapping` and `RKResponseDescriptor` for this response and check response class in `success` block, but how to notify RESTKit that responses that starts from "error" key path should be treated as errors even if status code is `200` and call `failure` block?

Comment: Why do you want to class it as a failure? Unless you wanted to map the error response to an `NSError` instance. Just deal with the result in the success block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is a small hack:

I made a subclass like:

```
@interface NutHTTPRequestOperation : RKHTTPRequestOperation

@end

@implementation NutHTTPRequestOperation
- (NSError *)error
{
    NSError * error = nil;
    //It seems only call to responseJSON could make AFJSONRequestOperation process error
    id object = [self.responseString objectFromJSONString];

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSNumber * ret = [object objectForKey:@"ret"];
        if (!ret || 0 != ret.integerValue) {
            NSString * desc = [object objectForKey:@"error"];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kNutResponseErrorDomain code:ret.integerValue userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: desc}];
        }
    }

    if(!error){
        //Get super error , if none, proceed self error
        NSError * error = [super error];
        if (error) {
            return error;
        }
        error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kNutResponseErrorDomain code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"not json dictionary"}];
    }
    return error;
}
```